# Loop IP address substitution in prewritten code

Tags: vbscript

I have code set up to telnet into a switch and tftp the startup-config to a server. This code works perfect if I hard code the IP address into the script.

What I would like to do is pass a list of IP addresses (one after the other) to the script so that I can copy all switch configs on the network. I have included some code below, this is the code I used to create the script. All I want to be able to do is replace the "telnet xx.xx.xx.xx" xx.xx.xx.xx entry with a list of IP addresses.

Thanks in advance!

Here is a copy of code I used:

```
Option Explicit

On Error Resume Next

Dim WshShell

set WshShell=CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

WshShell.run "cmd.exe"

WScript.Sleep 1000

'Send commands to the window as needed - IP and commands need to be customized

'Step 1 - Telnet to remote IP'

WshShell.SendKeys "telnet xx.xx.xx.xx"

WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")

WScript.Sleep 1000

'Step 2 - Issue Commands with pauses'

WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")

WScript.Sleep 1000

WshShell.SendKeys "5"

WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")

WScript.Sleep 1000

'Step 3 - Exit Command Window

WshShell.SendKeys "exit"

WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")

WScript.Quit
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, mostly your code with just a few lines inserted to loop through a list of IP addresses in plain text format.  Please let me know if this works for you.  Doing it this way opens a new command window for each telnet host and then closes it when its done.  It would probably be easy to modify to use the same command window.

```
Option Explicit

On Error Resume Next

Dim WshShell
Dim objFSO
Dim objInputFile
Dim strIP

set WshShell=CreateObject("WScript.Shell")


Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set objInputFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("IPFilelist.txt", 1)

Do Until objInputFile.AtEndofStream

    strIP = objInputFile.ReadLine

    WshShell.run "cmd.exe"

    WScript.Sleep 1000

    'Send commands to the window as needed - IP and commands need to be customized

    'Step 1 - Telnet to remote IP'

    WshShell.SendKeys "telnet " & strIP

    WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")

    WScript.Sleep 1000

    'Step 2 - Issue Commands with pauses'

    WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")

    WScript.Sleep 1000

    WshShell.SendKeys "5"

    WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")

    WScript.Sleep 1000

    'Step 3 - Exit Command Window

    WshShell.SendKeys "exit"

    WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")

Loop

WScript.Quit
```